# How to tweak models before rendering of the view

Tags: ember.js, models

I've been looking for a simple way to tweaks my Ember Data models before the view is rendered. How can I do this? I tried to use setupController but that doesn't seem right since they don't seem to be fetched yet.

**code:**

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("albums", { path: "/albums" }, function() {
    //this.resource('album', { path: ':album_id'});
  });
 });

 App.AlbumsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
     return App.Album.find(); 
   }
 });

 App.AlbumsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({ });
```

Thanks for your insight.

Comment: please define 'tweak models'

Comment: Assign a new property to use in handlebars templates

Comment: @user1732055 I've cleaned up your mess :)

Comment: Check [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/bskUT/). It has a little of everything. Might help you out. It's in CoffeeScript tho

Comment: App = Ember.Application.create({LOG_TRANSITIONS: true});

    App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
      revision: 12
    });


    App.Album = DS.Model.extend({})

    App.Router = Em.Router.extend({})


    App.Router.map(function() {
        this.resource("albums", { path: "/albums" }, function() {

        });
    });

    App.AlbumsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function() {
            return App.Album.find();
        }
    })
    App.AlbumsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({});

Comment: Thanks. First time posting a question on here.

Comment: Tip: you can edit the question. Check the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to interpret your "tweak models", a computed property (http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/) is maybe what you are looking for.

example:

**assuming a JSON like this**

```
{
  "albums": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "artist":"Pearl Jam",
      "title":"Jeremy",
      "genre":"Indipendent"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "artist":"Soundgarden",
      "title":"Superunknown",
      "genre":"Indipendent"
    }
  ]
}
```

**your model could be**

```
App.Album = DS.Model.extend({
  artist: DS.attr('string'),
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  genre: DS.attr('string'),

  quickInfo: function(){
    var artist = this.get('artist');
    var title = this.get('title');
    var genre = this.get('genre');

    return "This album is from " + artist + ", it's called " + title + " and is of genre " + genre;
  }.property('artist', 'title', 'genre');
});
```

**then in your handlebars**

```
...
{{#each album in model}}
  <li>{{ album.quickInfo }}</li>
{{/each}}
...
```

**html output**

`This album is from Pearl Jam, it's called Jeremy and is of genre Indipendent
...`

is this what you mean when you say

> tweaked models before rendering

?

hope it helps